# java :: Remove comma inside quotes inside String

Tags: java, split

```
String str = "a,b","c,d","1,2","5.6";
```

In the above I want to remove comma inside my double quotes. My result should be

```
str = "ab","cd","12","5.6".
```

I searched a lot to get the answer. It would be great if you can help me on JAVA.

Comment: Is str supposed to be a single `String` or a `String[]`?

Comment: I think your string assignment is wrong

Comment: The code you pasted is wrong. It wont compile.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your `String str` is not compilable. It should be

```
String str = "\"a,b\",\"c,d\",\"1,2\",\"5.6\"";
```

In order to replace `,` inside double quotes you need

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(\".?),(.?\")", "$1$2"));
```

Output:

```
"ab","cd","12","5.6"
```

Above solution assumes that you always have 1 or no character on both side of a `,` inside double quote.

If there can be multiple characters than those can also be matched using below expression

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(\"\\w*),(\\w*\")", "$1$2"));
```

Here `\w` is pre-defined character class to match `A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a String Array and replace all elements individually:

```
String[] replaceArray = {"a,b","c,d","1,2","5.6"};
for(int i=0; i<replaceArray.length; i++){
    replaceArray[i] = replaceArray[i].replaceAll(",","");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit ugly, but you could use two times `String#replace` - the first removing all commas, and the second re-adding the commas back between the quotes:

```
String str = "\"a,b\",\"c,d\",\"1,2\",\"5.6\"";
System.out.println(str.replace(",", "").replace("\"\"", "\",\""));
```

Output:

```
"ab","cd","12","5.6"
```

Perhaps better would be to use a regex to accomplish the same goal in one go, but that's not really my expertise to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code

```
        String str = "\"a,b\",\"c,d\",\"1,2\",\"5,6\"";
        str=str.replace("\"","");
        String[] parts = str.split(",");

        String outputString="";
        int literalCount=2;
        String output="";
        for (String part : parts) {
            if(literalCount==0) {
                outputString=outputString+output+",";
                output = part;
                literalCount=2;
            }else
            {
                output+=part;
            }
            literalCount--;

        }
        outputString="\""+outputString+output+"\"";
        System.out.println(outputString);
```